# Conditional date in where clause of mysql not filtering

Tags: php, mysql

I have written the code above which gets its values form a user. Its working but the date filter isn't working. Instead its displaying all the records in the table even when the dates are provided.

What could be the issue?

```php
$exp_query = "SELECT DISTINCT property_name, property_id, Water_charges, bank_charges, charge_1_description, other_charges_1,
                charge_2_description, other_charges_2, dates ";
$exp_query .="FROM expenses ";
$exp_query .="WHERE
              1=1
              AND (property_name= '".$property."'
                    OR dates BETWEEN '".$datefro."' AND '".$dateto."' )
                ";
```

Comment: What is "dates" field type ?

Comment: Kindly provide some sample data, the result you are getting and the expected result from that sample data.

Comment: @RanaGhosh its DATE type.

Comment: @Viki888 https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B1DJIDFn0RU9dHlsMi02SWl2b00 that is a screenshot of the results. As you can see, the dates in the result of the second table exceed the ones provided at date from and date to

Comment: @samuelkungu Please check my answer

Comment: @samuelkungu I have asked for sample data to understand your problem and reproduce your scenario. I can able to understand but surely no one can reproduce your scenario with the sample data provided. Kindly provide sample data in text format.

Comment: @Viki888 sorry for that. please use this. 1. dates- 2016-11-30, property_id- na1, expense- water, cost-200. 2.dates-2017-02-01, property_id -na1, expense- plumber, cost- 3000. 3 dates-2016-11-09, property_id-na1, expense-bankCharge, cost- 400.  The sample data is in field-value format.

Comment: @samuelkungu Really thanks for your sample data. Why do you have `OR` condition for `property_name` and `dates`? In your expected result that you  have provided in image format, I can able to understand that `property_name` is same for all the records in the expected result.

Comment: @Viki888 property_name is a must but dates is supposed to be optional. The sample data provided has only 1 property_name because i only filled used one property. its just a case study. But in real sense users will select different properties. What i want is, regardless of the property selected the displayed data should be within the date range selected. here's the form https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B1DJIDFn0RU9cG5HYjhkak1jNVE  Thanks

Comment: @samuelkungu So is it possible to select only dates in your form or only product_name in your form?

Comment: @Vikki888 sorry for late reply. I was busy. Dates only, no its not. Product name is the compulsory field to select. But the dates are optional.

Answer (score 0):

There is difference between AND and OR, also how to use OR with AND condition.
You have used an OR condition in parentheses, check them.

```
$exp_query = "SELECT DISTINCT property_name, property_id, Water_charges, bank_charges, charge_1_description, other_charges_1,
                charge_2_description, other_charges_2, dates ";
$exp_query .="FROM expenses ";
$exp_query .="WHERE property_name= '".$property."'
              AND (dates BETWEEN '".$datefro."' AND '".$dateto."' )";
```

Comment: Your solution is bringing more problems. Its not working

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using right condition in your **MYSQL** query

just use **MYSQL** `DATE()` function like::

```
$exp_query = "SELECT DISTINCT property_name, property_id, Water_charges, bank_charges, charge_1_description, other_charges_1,
                charge_2_description, other_charges_2, dates ";
$exp_query .="FROM expenses ";
$exp_query .="WHERE
              1=1
              AND (property_name= '".$property."'
                    OR DATE( dates ) BETWEEN '".$datefro."' AND '".$dateto."' )
                ";
```

Comment: Same results as before. Can you please cralify what you mean by right condition?

Comment: Right condition means we are assuming that you have written correct logic for where conditions.

Comment: @RanaI think user is getting extra rows because of wrong use of OR condition.